# Iptables to block http request on port 7880

Tags: http, port, iptables

I have a python service running on port 7880. 
In that server, I setup iptables rule for tcp/udp protocol and port 7880. For both INPUT and OUTPUT chain.

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 7880 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 7880 -j DROP
```

Still from other machine, I can access port 7880 using curl-X GET http://192.168.100.201:7880

[vagrant@worker-001 run]$ sudo iptables -L -n

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination
f2b-sshd-ddos  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22

f2b-sshd   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22

REJECT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:7880 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

REJECT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:7880 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

REJECT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:7880 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:7880

DROP       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:7880

DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80

DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:7880

DROP       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:7880

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination

REJECT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:7880 state ESTABLISHED reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

REJECT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:7880 state NEW,ESTABLISHED reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

REJECT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:7880 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

REJECT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:7880 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

REJECT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:7880 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:7880

DROP       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:7880

DROP       all  --  192.168.100.101      0.0.0.0/0

DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your problem: `--dport`

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 7880 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 7880 -j DROP
```

Comment: I think u are right. I added. But still not working. Should I restart iptables.service

Comment: No need for a restart. Check iptables -L. Rules are read from top to bottom. There could be some rules that match your request and allow it before it even reaches your new rules.